# Calling a Javascript function from java class

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Hi I have a javascript function like:

```
function abc(x,y,x)
{
      do something;

       while(condition)
      {
       do something;
      }
 }
```

I need to call this method from java class. Is it possible?

Comment: please provide more information as to in what type of circumstances you would want to call JS from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(jsFilePath));
```

Java has Scripting support using [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)

References:

- [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#who)

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the fact that **javascript is used for client side scripting** and using java we interact with server, databases. So if you want to talk to server then make **AJAX** calls. If you like jQuery then you can look for this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) .

Now if you just want to work in java style then there are few more beautiful libraries available which can make your life very easy.
Look for [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html), it provides a very easy way to interact with server. There are few configurations which you have to do so just go through the [documentation](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/index.html) it is very easy to implement.